# Navigating pages from listView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement navigation from a list view, when clicked on certain item a particular page should open, where i have multiple pages for each category available in the list

Comment: show some code, what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask